# JavaScript automatic redirect

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code in JavaScript wherein if the condition is null/false, the browser automatically redirects to another page. The only question is what are the codes for this block? Please help.

```
if(condition==false){
//redirect code
}
else
continue;
```

Comment: window.location.href="Your url"

Answer (score 3):

```
// try this
window.location = 'YOUR_URL';
```

Comment: you're quite the lifesaver

Answer (score 1):

```
if(condition==false){
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location = "URL TO REDIRECT";
```

or

```
window.location.replace("URL TO REDIRECT");
```

or

```
window.location.assign("URL TO REDIRECT");
```

or

```
window.location.href = "URL TO REDIRECT";
```

Remember to include "http://" or "https://" with your url. :)

Answer (score 0):

:) use code bellow

```
               if( condition== null /false ) 
            { 
                 alert(" Ohhooo.. Redirected ");
                 window.location.replace('http://url');


                // another code
                // location.href = "url.html";


                // u can also use time out code after time page redirect
                //setTimeout("location.href = 'http://url';",1500);


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this tested!

```
 window.location.assign("URL");
```

e.g.

`window.location.assign("http://www.google.com");`